# google maps v3 translate map.getPane(G_MAP_FLOAT_SHADOW_PANE)

Tags: google-maps

can anyone tell me what the translation from v2 to v3 of this line of code is please?

map.getPane(G_MAP_FLOAT_SHADOW_PANE)

I know it's related to - google.maps.MapPanes but not sure of the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a custom overlay. For information on adding overlays to specific panes see here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Initializing

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
map.getPanes().floatShadow
```

to get floatShadow pane object.

Comment: map.getPanes() is not possible, it is not a function exposed in the google.maps.Map object.