# JQuery append to map pane

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm switching one of my projects over to use googles maps api v3 from v2.

In v2 I had a div appended to the map pane with the following code:

```
$("#marker_popup").appendTo(map.getPane(G_MAP_FLOAT_SHADOW_PANE));
```

Is there any simple way to do that with v3? I've been searching around and I've found some things relating to implementing draw and onAdd, but I figure there has to be an easier way to do it than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the answer to this question (and the corresponding v3 API documentation): [google maps v3 translate map.getPane(G_MAP_FLOAT_SHADOW_PANE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403032/google-maps-v3-translate-map-getpaneg-map-float-shadow-pane)